# C++ rapidly refresh desktop

Tags: c++, windows, animation, desktop

I am trying to make a program currently that outputs a polygon to the desktop for a simple animation. The problem I am currently running into is that the animation gets an "onion" effect because the desktop isn't refreshing. I have searched for a method to refresh the desktop however because it's an animation, none of the solutions can refresh it fast enough. Below is an example of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>


int main() {    
    //start ambrose
    POINT amby[5];
    POINT pos;
    /* hide console window */
    ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false);
    /* Calling GetDC with argument 0 retrieves the desktop's DC */
    HDC hDC_Desktop = GetDC(0);

    //This is just an example of what I am doing

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

        pos.x = 600+sin(double(i)/50)*200;
        pos.y = 500+cos(double(i)/50)*200;
        amby[0].x = -10+pos.x;
        amby[0].y = -10+pos.y;
        amby[1].x = -50+pos.x;
        amby[1].y = -50+pos.y;
        amby[2].x = 50+pos.x;
        amby[2].y = -50+pos.y;

        Polygon(hDC_Desktop,amby, 3);
        Sleep(10);
    }
    //The method I was trying before that didn't work VVVVV
    //LPITEMIDLIST pidl;
    //SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(NULL,CSIDL_DESKTOP,&pidl);
    //SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED,SHCNF_IDLIST,pidl,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

## Edit

I have tried using invalidateRect as such:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

    pos.x = 600+sin(double(i)/50)*200;
    pos.y = 500+cos(double(i)/50)*200;
    amby[0].x = -10+pos.x;
    amby[0].y = -10+pos.y;
    amby[1].x = -50+pos.x;
    amby[1].y = -50+pos.y;
    amby[2].x = 50+pos.x;
    amby[2].y = -50+pos.y;

    Polygon(hDC_Desktop,amby, 3);
    InvalidateRect(GetDesktopWindow(),NULL, true);
    Sleep(10);
}
...
```

**I am wondering if there is anyway to call WM_ERASEBKGND or WM_DISPLAYCHANGE to force a change. Does anyone know if there is a way to call these?**

Comment: This needs an additional tag since plain C++ cannot draw polygons.

Comment: Looks like Windows - I've added a tag now.

Comment: Why on earth are you painting to the _desktop_ rather than a window of your own? Why do you start by hiding a random console window?

Comment: The program runs in a console window, so it hides that. It uses window.h for the drawing. The reason I am drawing to the desktop, is so that I can have an animation that is not bound by a window. Thank you for adding that tag Paul.

Comment: Well, you might be able to use InvalidateRect to force a paint, but you don't own the desktop, so using it in such a way is just the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @user1642826: You're not hiding the console window of your program -- you're hiding _whatever random console window `FindWindow` finds for you_ -- which may or may not be the one where your program is running. But why does your program have a console window at all if all you want to do with it is hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Let me just answer to problem of onion effect. A quick and dirty solution to erase what was drawn in the previous iteration could be to draw using XOR mode but the solution has a few downsides, like flicker and color could be arbitrary. A proper solution that would address both the downsides would be to do all the drawing in a memory DC and BitBlt the same to the screen.

Code for the quick and dirty solution would be -

```
SetROP2(hDC_Desktop,R2_XORPEN);
//This is just an example of what I am doing

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
{
    if(i!=0)
    {
        pos.x = 600+sin(double(i-1)/50)*200;
        pos.y = 500+cos(double(i-1)/50)*200;
        amby[0].x = -10+pos.x;
        amby[0].y = -10+pos.y;
        amby[1].x = -50+pos.x;
        amby[1].y = -50+pos.y;
        amby[2].x = 50+pos.x;
        amby[2].y = -50+pos.y;

                    Polygon(hDC_Desktop,amby, 3);
    }

    pos.x = 600+sin(double(i)/50)*200;
    pos.y = 500+cos(double(i)/50)*200;
    amby[0].x = -10+pos.x;
    amby[0].y = -10+pos.y;
    amby[1].x = -50+pos.x;
    amby[1].y = -50+pos.y;
    amby[2].x = 50+pos.x;
    amby[2].y = -50+pos.y;

    Polygon(hDC_Desktop,amby, 3);
    Sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: For more complex objects, it doesn't work. Though when searching up that function I found a few functions I wish to try. I found one that works, PaintDesktop(hDC_Desktop);, however it removes all desktop items. (folders, start bar, etc...)

Comment: Just to add, after doing some tinkering I would recommend SetROP2(hDC_Desktop,R2_NOTXORPEN); , as it removes the color problem. And if you do the invert after the new paste you get less to no flashing.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy solution, and that's to not actually draw on the desktop. Instead, create a **transparent** full-screen window. Since it's transparent, any pixel that you don't draw will show the desktop underneath. Hence, only your polygon pixels will hide the underlying desktop.

As a result, the desktop window never needs to be invalidated or repainted etc.

Comment: This was given as an answer before, but i need to click through the screen at the same time that the program was running.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a transparent wnd.

```
class COverlayWnd : public CWnd
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(COverlayWnd)

public:
    COverlayWnd();
    virtual ~COverlayWnd();

protected:
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

// OverlayWnd.cpp : implementation file
//
```

The implementation. Just move the window if you want animations to run all over the desktop.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

// COverlayWnd

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(COverlayWnd, CWnd)

COverlayWnd::COverlayWnd()
{
}

COverlayWnd::~COverlayWnd()
{
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(COverlayWnd, CWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_CREATE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void COverlayWnd::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect( &rect );
    dc.FillSolidRect(&rect, RGB(1,1,1));
    //paint other stuff that don't have RGB(1,1,1)

}


int COverlayWnd::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    BOOL bRet = 0;

    bRet = ModifyStyleEx(0,WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
    bRet = ModifyStyle(DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU,0);
    bRet = ModifyStyle(WS_POPUP,0);
    bRet = SetLayeredWindowAttributes(RGB(1,1,1),0,LWA_COLORKEY);
    //the RGB(1,1,1) is the transparent color 
    ASSERT(bRet);
    //this->EnableWindow(FALSE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would this allow for clicking "through" the animation?

Comment: No, so far as I know. Maybe if you use PreTranslateMessage so that it sends the key-down and mouse events through the window...

Comment: Full plan through, I know its not the best idea, but I want to make a desktop "pet". So you would need to click through it for it to not be annoying.

Comment: please look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12365/How-to-make-a-transparent-and-click-through-window... sorry I read the article and it uses WTL and VS2005...Probably not applicable for your case

Comment: @user1642826: Sounds thoroughly annoying, but if you do want to do this a better way would be to create a _small_ transparent window just large enough to show your pet, and move that window around as it moves. Have the pet wander away if you click on it, such that the user gets to interact with the actual desktop underneath. (Unless if the pet is a cat, in which case the proper behavior is to refuse to budge and _not_ let mouse clicks through. You needed that shortcut? Tough luck.).